# how to use action listener on a button in a different class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

I'm fairly new to GUIs and am having trouble with this assignment. Basically we have eight classes total and have to use three panel classes three different ways, one way using only the TopPanel and InitialPanel classes, one using only the BottomPanel and and InitialPanel class, and one using only the InitialPanel class. The goal is to make a button in the bottom panel display info about a football player when the button in the top panel is pressed.                             `

```
public class BottomPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    public JButton b1;
    public BottomPanel(final JPanel topPanel)
    {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.pink);
        //setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        b1 = new JButton("When the user clicks on the button in the UPPER panel, displays the football player's position here" );

        add(b1);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        Object obj = event.getSource();
        if(obj == b1)
        {
            b1.setText(fp1.getPosition());
        }
    }




}



public class InitialPanel extends JPanel 
{
    public InitialPanel()
{
    super();
    setBackground(Color.gray);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    TopPanel p1 = new TopPanel();
    add(p1,"North");

    BottomPanel p2 = new BottomPanel(p1);
    add(p2,"Center");




}


}`

public class TopPanel extends JPanel
{   
    public TopPanel()
    {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.yellow);        
        footballPlayer fp1 = new footballPlayer("Mark","Allen",22, "IST", 5.6f, 180, "Junior","Running Back");
        // the whatsUp of this student has to shown in the other panel      
        JButton jl1 = new JButton(fp1.getInfo());
        add(jl1);
    }
}`
```

I think i got the only TopPanel and InitialPanel running, but am stuck on what do to for the other two. Also, getInfo() is the method to call when setting the text of the bottom button, and we CANNOT create another footballplayer object other than the one being used in TopPanel. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already added `jl1` button to the `TopPanel`, now you should add a listener to that button: you can add it at the `BottomPanel` class.

You receive a reference to `topPanel` in the `BottomPanel` constructor so you can keep him as a member and create the listener, something like this:

```
public class BottomPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    public JButton b1;

    /** added member to topPanel **/
    private JPanel mTopPanel;

    public BottomPanel(final JPanel topPanel)
    {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.pink);

        this.mTopPanel = topPanel;

        b1 = new JButton("When the user clicks on the button in the UPPER             
        panel, displays the football player's position here" );

        add(b1);

        /** the topPanel jli button listener **/
        this.mTopPanel.jl1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
             {
                 /** edit your button with the info of the player **/
                 b1.setText("player info added here");
             }
        });
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        Object obj = event.getSource();
        if(obj == b1)
        {
            b1.setText(fp1.getPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Everything looks good except for one thing, the objects of TopPanel are still not being recognized, is there a way to associate mTopPanel with the TopPanel class?

Comment: How is not recognize? If the constructor of BottomPanel receive top panel as a parameter?

Comment: I'm not really sure, how does final JPanel topPanel connect to the TopPanel class? I think thats the problem

Answer (score 1):

You should register the bottom panel as a `Listener` of the button in the top panel. To achieve this, you should make a list storing all the listeners to the button in your `TopPanel` class. And once the button is pressed, the current player's information will be broadcast to all the listeners. And what you need to do is to make `ButtonPanel` class implement the `Listener` which here I call it `DisplayPlayerInfoListener`.

```
class TopPanel extends JPanel {

    JButton displayButton = new JButton("show player info");

    FootballPlayer currentPlayer = new FootballPlayer();
    List<DisplayPlayerInfoListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public TopPanel() {
        add(displayButton);
        displayButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                displayButtonPressed();
            }
        });
    }

    void displayButtonPressed() {
        for (DisplayPlayerInfoListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.displayPlayer(currentPlayer);
        }
    }

    public void addDisplayPlayerInfoListener(DisplayPlayerInfoListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
}

interface DisplayPlayerInfoListener {
   void displayPlayer(FootballPlayer player);
}

class BottomPanel extends JPanel implements DisplayPlayerInfoListener {

    @Override
    public void displayPlayer(FootballPlayer player) {
        // show the player's information on your bottom panel's UI
    }
}
```

somewhere in your code, you will need to add the bottom panel as a listener to the top panel's button.

```
topPanel.addDisplayPlayerInfoListener(bottomPanel);
```

By doing this, you can register as many listeners as you want since this information might need to be broadcast to other UI components as well. Also, it separates the two panels, you don't need to get the information by access one of the other panels fields on methods. The information will be handled when the it's ready to send. The TopPanel only sees the BottomPanel as a DisplayPlayerInfoListener instance thus there's less coupling.